# Complex android layout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I need to make layout with 4 TextView.

First TextView places at the left bound of screen, second TextView may hav different sizes, third TextView places after second textView and fourth TextView places at the right bound of screen.

If second TextView is short, after third TextView adds empty space like:

```
[TextView1 TextView2 TextView3 (free space) TextView4]
```

If second TextView is long, it ellipsize with ... at the end:

```
[TextView1 VeryLooooooongTexVi... TextView3 TextView4]
```

How can I write this layout in xml? I must use LinearLayout or TableLayout is better? Can you give any examples?

Comment: try to give wheight to your textviews's and use Linearlayout

Comment: You could play around with weight and maxWidth

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **RelativeLayout** for aligning the textviews the way you want using the attributes layout_**alignParentLeft**,layout_**alignParentRight** and layout_**toRightOf**.
The second **TextView** can be designed in the required way by using **maxWidth, ellipsize, singleLine** attributes of TextView.
The layout will be somewhat like this:

```
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="first"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="secondtextviewlonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/thirdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="third"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/fourthTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="fourth"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, you can find an example project of different layouts [here](https://github.com/asnehal/Layouts.git)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<View
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```